# [Lubuntu]Failure attempting to update nodejs with nvm

Tags: lubuntu, nodejs

I'm using Lubuntu in an old laptop.

My current version of nodejs is 8.10.0, and I wanted to update it at least to the latest LTS version, but when I try to install this happens:

This is the error message:

[image: screenshot of terminal]

I don't know what I could do, or what you recommend, anyways I would be really thankful if you can help me, but if I can't do anything I'll stick with the current version I have.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text output - instead copy the text and [edit] your question to paste the copied text.

Comment: Please also provided you release details.  (we can guess from the picture, but it's far better if we're told & not making assumptions/guesses).